# Unable to play videos on some particular websites

Tags: google-chrome, video, browser

I am using the Chrome browser on Windows, and I am able to play videos on youtube. But I am unable to play videos on some websites like hotstar.com, because the browser shows only a blank black screen. I have the Adobe Flash Player plugin in my Chrome browser.

What may be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome [removed support for flash](https://blog.google/products/chrome/flash-and-chrome/) back in May 16'. You will need to use a different browser.

Comment: i just installed adobe flash player and trying to use it with mozilla browser.But then also i am seeing a blank screen when i try to play a video.

Comment: @a874 - I believe Mozilla also removed Flash support